# Send an object in JSON format and convert it back

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I tried to send this string to a php file and convert it there back.

```
$htmlparts= '{"footer.html" : "<div id="footer" class="tpl_area edtr_element" contenteditable="true"><footer class="container" id="1194">...</footer></div>","page_index.html" : "<div id="pagecontent" class="tpl_area edtr_element" contenteditable="true">...</div>","header.html" : "<div id="header" class="tpl_area edtr_element" contenteditable="true"><header id="1094"><nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark" data-editor-id="1095" id="1095">...  </nav>
</header></div>" }';
```

Used following method to call ajax:

```
data={'htmlparts': htmlparts, ...somethings more...}

$.ajax({
            url: url,
            method: 'POST',
            data: data,
            dataType:'json',
...
```

In the console, i am seeing "htmlparts" getting called correctly:

In php (codeigniter project) I tried to get this content

```
$test=json_decode($_POST['htmlparts']);
                echo"<pre>";
                print_r($test);
                echo"<pre>";
```

but as result I get nothing (only `<pre></pre>`)

What did i do wrong?

Comment: maybe instead of $ctn variable you want to print $test?

Comment: yes, but is was only a mistake to this post, i update this - thanks

Comment: another thing is that json_decode is returning an array or object. In this case should be object. So you need to specify $test->something or array $test['footer.html']. Check the php manual https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: sorry, but print_r($test) should output this!?

Comment: in your ajax add `contentType: application/json` and you need to stringify data to json `JSON.stringify(data)`

Comment: Your $htmlparts is not contains a valid JSON, You can check your JSON is valid or not in https://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust the json object to this format:

```
data = {
  "div": "something",
  "span": "something"
}
```

Also you need to stringify this object.

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST` will be empty array in your case. Try using this

`$decoded = json_decode(trim(file_get_contents("php://input")), true);`

`$decoded` will contain the parsed JSON received from frontend.

Comment: no post contains the complete string, it is not empty!

Answer (score 0):

To send `json` in your `ajax post` request, your request requires `contentType` and data should be encoded to `json` like:

```
data={'htmlparts': htmlparts, ...somethings more...}

$.ajax({
  url: url,
  method: 'POST',
  // notice the changes here
  contentType: 'application/json'
  data: JSON.stringify(data),
...
```